# TypeError: event() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'coro'

Tags: discord.py

This is my code so far. I don't under stand what is wrong with it..

```
import os
import discord

client = discord.Client

@client.event 
async def on_ready():  <--- This part errors
  print('Bot is Online')

client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you forgot the brackets when defining your Client. Also `intents` is a required argument now, so you need to set those as well.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

Quickstart docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html